# How to select all rows which have a field equal to {}

Tags: postgresql

I see few records like this in my `table`:

```
     id  | val
 --------+------------
    1    | {}
    2    | {}
```

Of course not all are equal to {}, and I would like to query them out and then update them to {0}. However, trying the following fails:

```
UPDATE table SET val={0} WHERE val={};
```

I must be missing something obvious, please point out what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET val='{0}' WHERE val='{}';
```

Comment: Ah, bloody hell. Thx. Indeed, not one of my best days. I'll accept the answer after the grace period for acceptance is over (currently 8 mins). Thx once again.